# Reflection positivity on weighted $L^2$-spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory

Denote by $(t, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{d-1})$  the coordinates of $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and  set
$$\mathbb{R}^{d}_{+}=\left\{t, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{d-1} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}|t > 0\right\}. $$
Write $\theta$ for the reflection
$$(t, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{d-1}) \mapsto (-t, x_{1}, \ldots, x_{d-1}).$$ as well as for the induced map on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{d})$.

The resolvent $C=(1-\Delta)^{-1}$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, is known to be reflection positive on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{d})$, i.e., one has
$$ \langle C f ,\theta f \rangle_{L^2} \geq 0$$
for all $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d}_{+})$, the compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^{d}_{+}$.

Fix $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and set $\rho(x)=(1+\|x\|)^s$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Is $C$ reflection positive on the weighted $L^2$-space with weight $\rho$ ? In other words, is it true that
$$ \langle C f ,\rho \hspace{2pt}\theta f \rangle_{L^2} \geq 0$$
for all $f \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{d}_{+})$ ?

Comment: Isn't this tantamount to the question whether $\rho C$ is reflection positiive?

Comment: @gmvh : Certainly it is.